# Understanding closure and scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

For some reason (probably because i don't understand closures) function `inResult` always returns `false` and the loop is never executed. Of course i'm sure that `result` contains has the right properties.

```
    function hasId() {return $(this).prop('id');}
    function inResult(res) { return res.hasOwnProperty($(this).prop('id'));}

    $.ajax({
        url : opt.url,
        data : $.extend(true, opt.data, {ids: ids}),
        context : this, // A collection of elements
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {

            // Filter elements with id and with a property in result named "id"
            this.filter(hasId).filter(inResult(result)).each(function() {
                console.log($(this).prop('id'));
            });

        }
    });
```

**EDIT**: working code solution (thanks to **Šime Vidas** for poiting me in the right direction):

```
// Use closures to change the context later
var hasId    = function() { return $(this).prop('id'); };
var inResult = function(res) { return res.hasOwnProperty($(this).prop('id')); };

$.ajax({
    url : opt.url,
    data : $.extend(true, opt.data, {ids: ids}),
    context : this, // A collection of elements
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result) {

        // Filter elements with id and with a property in result named "id"
        var filtered = this.filter(function() {
            // Note the context switch and result parameter passing
            return hasId.call(this) && isBinded.call(this, result);
        });

        filtered.each(function() { console.log($(this).prop('id')); });

    }
});
```

Comment: `this.id` works fine. No need for `prop()`.

Comment: Closures are not jQuery-specific, they are one of the JavaScript features.

Comment: @zizozu you right, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.filter( hasId ).filter( function () {
    return inResult( result );
}).each( function () {
    console.log( this.id );
});
```

In your code you have `.filter(inResult(result))` which won't work because you're invoking `inResult` immediately and passing the *result* of that invocation (which is a Boolean value) to `filter()`, which doesn't work with Boolean values.

---

You could also do it like so:

```
var keys = Object.keys( result );

var filtered = this.filter( function () {
    return this.id && keys.indexOf( this.id ) > -1;
});
```

`Object.keys( result )` returns an array of all own property names from `result`.

Comment: `filter()` can be used with function that returns boolean values, so there is nothing wrong with mine i think..

Comment: @Gremo But you're not passing the function to `filter()`. You're passing a Boolean value to it. `filter( true )` doesn't work. You have to pass a function to it.

Comment: Got it! So the only way is to wrap che call into a new `function`? Guess why `hasId` it's working...

Comment: @Gremo There is the `bind` function method, so `.filter( inResult.bind( this, result ) )` should also work. (However, `bind` is not implemented in IE8 and Safari, so you would have to include ES5-shim to your web-page.)

Comment: However the keyword `this` inside `inResult` will still refer to the window object...

Comment: @Gremo Yes, I'm not sure how to fix that. With `bind` we have to explicitly set the `this` value of the function.

Comment: With a "real" closure like `var inResult = function(res) { ... }` context can be changed using `inResult.call(this)` inside the `filter` function. However i don't know how to change the context when function is not a closure.